# Triggers in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, triggers

I am having trouble with the following problem, Just wondering if you could give me any guidance on how i would start this.

> Write a trigger to capture an input before it's inserted into a table
>   so that the value of the insert will be modified to be appended with
>   the text  `-previous`

Say I have a table called StaffDetails and i could insert info such as ID, How would i apply it to the above problem.

Thank You

Comment: This is called a **before-insert trigger**. In this trigger you see the new values and you can change them before the data is actually written.

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_insert.php looks clear and relevant.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thank you, that looks great!

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Trigger trg_name
on StaffDetails 
instead of insert
referencing new as new_row
as
begin
@new_row.ID = (@new_row.ID + '_previous')
insert into StaffDetails (.....) values (@new_row.ID, .....)
end
```

it would probably look something like this, maybe youll have to change some syntax because its not the same for mysql and sql server, for detailed information on syntax for sql server you can look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: The question is for Oracle.

Comment: @Aleksa Thanks, not sure if this is what i was looking for but i appreciate the help :)